# How do I deal with "Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" in Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a script to scrape product names from a website, filtered by brands. Some search results may contain more than one page, and this is where the problem comes in. I'm able to scrape the first page but when the script clicks on the next page the error message `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` shows. Below is my code:

```
def scrape():
   resultList = []
   currentPage = 1

   while currentPage <= 2:
      titleResults = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h4.mt-0')))
      resultList.append(titleResults)
      checkNextPage = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div/nav/ul/li/a[@aria-label='Next']")))
      for cnp in checkNextPage:
         nextPageNumber = int(cnp.get_attribute("data-page"))
      currentPage += 1
      driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/nav/ul/li/a[@aria-label='Next']").click()
   for result in resultList[0]:
      print("Result: {}".format(result.text))
```

I think the error got triggered when `.click()` was called. I've done a lot of searching on the internet before resorting to posting this question here because either I don't understand the solutions from other articles/posts or they don't apply to my case.

Comment: Not 100% sure if it's the problem, but could you try to append titleResults.text instead of titleResults? The fact is that resultList contains a list of web elements attached to the first page, but after the click the elements become "stale" because the page has changed, so the elements are not attached to the page document anymore and you can't print the results' text. If you append the text instead of the web element, the fact that the webpage has changed is not relevant, so it should work.

Comment: the problem is that visibility of all elements returns if at least 1 element is found.  It does not know how many items may become present or visible.  So the DOM may still be updating.  (In your code Stale Element will be thrown when using cnp.get_attribute)  Next Buttons>1? The best thing to do is functionize the driver call and try/catch the stale element exception... if it's caught, try again (re-call function).  Use a counter as a sanity check... if counter = 2*WebDriverWait timeout don't re-call.   (WebDriverWait polls at 1/2 second intervals and throws Timeout or StaleElement)

Comment: alternatively just add a sleep before getting the checkNextPage array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stale Element means an old element or no longer available element.

I think the error is caused by last line.

You should extract elements text before the elements become unavailable.

```
def scrape():
   resultList = []
   currentPage = 1

   while currentPage <= 2:
      titleResults = WebDriverWait(driver, 
10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h4.mt-0')))

      // Extract elements text 
      results_text = [titleResults[i].text for i in range(0, len(titleResults))]
      resultList.extend(results_text)

      checkNextPage = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div/nav/ul/li/a[@aria-label='Next']")))
      for cnp in checkNextPage:
         nextPageNumber = int(cnp.get_attribute("data-page"))
      currentPage += 1
      driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/nav/ul/li/a[@aria-label='Next']").click()


  print("Result: {}".format(resultList))
```